# non-repeating characters regex

Tags: regex, regex-negation

A colleague uses a application which uses regular expressions to validate data entry fields.

He needs to allows users to choose from digits 1-9.

i.e. 1, 2, 3, ..., 12, 13, ..., 23, 24, ..., ..., 123456789

The obvious basic [1-9]{1,9} would not disallow repeated digits or enforce numerical order.

A digit cannot be repeated (disallow 11, 343, etc.) and they must be in numerical order (disallow 21, 164, etc).

Short of matching the 320 possibilities separately "(1|2|3|...|12|13|...)", how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
^1?2?3?4?5?6?7?8?9?$
```

This one?

Clearly the user can insert up to 9 digits (123456789) and he can start from any one. Any digit is optional, but the order is fixed.

If you want a digit to be necessary, use a look ahead

```
^(?=[1-9])1?2?3?4?5?6?7?8?9?$
```

or look behind

```
^1?2?3?4?5?6?7?8?9?(?<=[1-9])$
```

or negative look ahead

```
^(?!$)1?2?3?4?5?6?7?8?9?$
```

or negative look behind

```
^1?2?3?4?5?6?7?8?9?(?<!^)$
```

so at least a digit is necessary

If your regex language doesn't have look aheads (and look behinds) you can do:

```
^12?3?4?5?6?7?8?9?|23?4?5?6?7?8?9?|34?5?6?7?8?9?|45?6?7?8?9?|56?7?8?9?|67?8?9?|78?9?|89?|9)$
```

Now the first digit "branches" to the "valid" combination of following optional digits.

Comment: That's not too shabby, except it matches `""` :-) That could be fixed with a `length > 0` constraint.

Comment: Right, I'll give you +1 for that, then :-) Though it's a simple fix for the OP to make, you may want to get rid of the zero (since the Q called for digits 1 thru 9).

Comment: Great answer @xanatos and obvious now I've seen it!

I've since found out that each digit has an optional suffix of a-d so I've suggested
`^(1|1a|1b|1c|1d)?(2|2a|2b|2c|2d)?(3...9d)?$`
it just remains to be seen whether the app's regex engine supports it...

Thanks